# MVC Error: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'Value''

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

There seem to be a few other questions similar to this but in those instances the error thrown is specific to the field that the person is selecting out of model. In my case it just seem to be throwing a generic error any time I try to access something from the model. The model I am using is an Entity Framework generated class which used to work, however, this seems related to me moving the class into a Class Library that is separate from the actual MVC project.  Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Here's the code and below is a screenshot of the error:

```
@model Gravy.Utility.Transaction

@{ ViewBag.Title = "Rental Request"; }
<script>
    var transaction_guid = "@Model.TransactionGUID";
</script>
<div id="rental_request_content" class="body_content">
    <div class="page_heading">Rental Request</div>
    <div class="heading">Transaction Details</div>
    <div id="approval_item_title">Model.ItemName</div>
    <div id="approval_item_image" style="backgroud-image: url(http://images.rentery.net/dev/items/@Model.ItemGUID)"></div>
    <div id="approval_transction_info">
        <div class="review_cost_line">
            <div>Rental Start Date</div>
            <div id="approval_start_date">@Model.RentalStart</div>
        </div>
        <div class="review_cost_line">
            <div>Rental End Rate</div>
            <div id="approval_end_date">@Model.RentalEnd</div>
        </div>
        <div class="review_cost_line">
            <div>Rental Income</div>
            <div id="review_rate_total">@Model.RentalCost</div>
        </div>
        <div class="review_cost_line">
            <div>Rentery Fee</div>
            <div id="review_rental_fee">@Model.OwnerRentalFee</div>
        </div>
        <div class="review_cost_line">
            <div></div>
            <div><hr /></div>
        </div>
        <div id="review_total_row" class="review_cost_line">
            <div>Rental Revenue</div>
            <div id="review_grand_total"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="approval_button" value="@ViewBag.ApproveDeny.Value" class="button">@ViewBag.ApproveDeny.Text.ToLower()</div>
    <div><div id="approval_subtext" value="@ViewBag.ApproveDenyOpposite.Value">Actually, @ViewBag.ApproveDenyOpposite.Text.ToLower() the rental</div></div>
</div>
```

[image: Error]

Comment: Care to show us your controller and model class?

Comment: @stephen-muecke If I knew how to reproduce this I could work out a solution myself. I don't know how to reproduce it that is why I am asking for suggestions in the first place. The alternative is I share the entirety of the project I am working on which I cannot possibly due because I am legally bound not to. Therefore you have made it impossible to actually get help on the one place that used to be full of helpful and intelligent people. I'm providing enough detail for someone to take a guess at what's going on. SO has turned into a totalitarian dictatorship rather than a helpful community.

Comment: MVC consists of 3 parts. You showed only the **V**. All you needed to do was to include the Model and Controller code associated with that view as was requested.

Comment: Marco requested it but none of the mods who flagged the post did. The "put on hold" section just gave a cryptic, non-specific reason. As a user posting on the forum, having specific feedback from a mod (not sure a random user) about what I should fix to meet guidelines would have been useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did not **declared your Viewbag.Aprovedeny.Value** variable before using it. Check it please.
It would be good uf you have updated your question with the controller too.

Comment: Thanks Karen, you're right. The green highlight from Visual Studio was throwing me for a loop but the object in ViewBag was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Some fields of Model were already successfully used, so you have a specific problem with `@Model.OwnerRentalFee`. Make sure it is defined properly and it has a Value which can be displayed.